# AutoHotKey script activates only on numpad enter

Tags: autohotkey

My script is only activating when I press the numpad enter, is it possible for it to work if I press the big enter?

Here is what I have, when I type test + numpad enter then it invokes ctr+shift+u

:*:test`n::test^+u

I need the other enter to work or both if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
:*:test`n::bob
```

And it types bob no matter which enter key I push.  If you use `n, that doesn't necessarily indicate that you are pushing any`enter`key - it just means you are inserting a carriage return - so either`enter` key will do that.  But your text area must be able to receive and insert a carriage return.

That means, that if you are working in a single-line text box, it can't receive a carriage return, in which case, using `n won't work for you.

You might also assure that the active window is able to receive ^!u and do something with that.

Comment: I need this to enable a script while I'm in visual studio where it is multi line for sure. However, you can test for instance in notepad++ and if you have icons enabled you can see that it turns on if you type test + numpadenter but not if I use the other enter. I'm very new to autohotkey but the n is described here http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars although it only works for one enter key as I said

Comment: sorry, you dont need the icons to see it as long as you see that it changed test to bob like in your example. I have also tested in standard notepad and i have the same problem, so im sure its not a visual studio / notepad ++ or notepad problem, its overall

Comment: Is your numberpad lock on?

Comment: When I used "bob" it worked on my computer using both enter keys.  Does bob work on your computer?

Comment: What if you tried ``r``n` instead of just `n` ?  Windows uses both `r`n in many cases to indicate a carriage return.